# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with Windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I am trying to connect to SQL Server - with .NET 6 it works fine, but I want to migrate it to .NET 8.

I have tried several things:

- adding `app.UseAuthentication();` in my `program.cs` and adding annotation `[Authorize]` in my controller

To make connection I am calling a class via dependency injection in my controller. I have added transient for both classes in my `program.cs` and in the dependency.

When I run it like this, it always asks for Windows credentials and I can't authorize.

When I run it without `app.UseAuthentication();` in my `program.cs`, it returns null connection in my DAO.

Here is my code - `DBFactory`:

```
public SqlConnection Get()
{
    \#if RELEASE
    var theConnectionString = "Data Source=serverName; Initial Catalog=dbName; Integrated Security=true;";
    \#else
    var theConnectionString = "Data Source=serverName; Initial Catalog=dbName; Integrated Security=true;";
    \#endif

    return new SqlConnection(theConnectionString);
}
```

DAO:

```
private readonly IDBFactory _factory;

public LocationsDAO(IDBFactory factory)
{
    _factory = factory;
}

public List<LocationData> GetAllLocations()
{
    using SqlConnection connection = _factory.Get();

    return connection.Query<LocationData>(SQLQueries.GetAllLocations).ToList();
}
```

API controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/")]
public class LocationsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILocationsDAO _locationDAO;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpC;

    public LocationsController(ILocationsDAO locationDAO, IHttpContextAccessor _httpC)
    {
        _locationDAO = locationDAO;
        httpC = _httpC;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<LocationData> GetAllLocations()
    {
        var locations = _locationDAO.GetAllLocations();
        return locations;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix the problem with connecting to database in my API project I made this false: `<InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>`, but I still have the problem with windows authentication